# How to create a fulltext index on a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, full-text-search

I'd like to create a FULLTEXT index on my view but I can't and I don't see what the problem is.

My view with unique clustered index:

```
-- View Creation
CREATE VIEW View_School_Degree WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    SELECT
        s.Id_School [School Id]
        ,s.Name [School Name]
        ,s.Type
        ,s.Code
        ,CAST(CONCAT(s.Address1, N' ',s.Address2  , N', ', s.Address3, N' ', s.Address4) AS nvarchar(500)) [Postal Address]
        ,s.Email
        ,d.Id_Degree [Degree Id]
        ,d.Title [Degree Title]
        ,d.[Option] [Degree Option]
        ,CAST(CONCAT(d.Code, N' / ', d.[Option]) AS [nvarchar]) [Degree / Option]
        ,sd.Capacity
    FROM dbo.School_Degree sd
    JOIN dbo.School s ON s.Id_School = sd.Id_School
    JOIN dbo.Degree d ON d.Id_Degree = sd.Id_Degree
GO

-- INDEX Creation
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_School_Degree_Identifier] ON dbo.View_School_Degree
(
    [School Id] ASC,
    [Degree Id] ASC
)
```

My FULLTEXT index creation with FULLTEXT catalog :

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG SchoolCatalog
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.View_School_Degree
(
    [School Name] LANGUAGE 1036
    ,[Degree Title] LANGUAGE 1036
    ,[Postal Address] LANGUAGE 1036
)
KEY INDEX IX_View_School_Degree_Identifier
ON SchoolCatalog
WITH STOPLIST OFF;
GO
```

I get this error:

> 'IX_View_School_Degree_Identifier' is not a valid index for applying a full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique index that does not accept the value Null, has only one column not offline, is not defined on a calculated non-deterministic or imprecise non-persistent column, has no filter, and has a maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another index for the full text key

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @DavidG SQL Server returns the following error but I don't see the problem:
IX_View_School_Degree_Identifier' is not a valid index for applying a full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique index that does not accept the value Null, has only one column not offline, is not defined on a calculated non-deterministic or imprecise non-persistent column, has no filter, and has a maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another index for the full text key.

Comment: So there you go, that error tells you the exact problem...

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, sorry, I had two columns in my index. The tiredness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, this part says:

> IX_View_School_Degree_Identifier' is not a valid index .... has only one column

However your index is made up from two columns. You need to create a new index that satisfies those requirements